# jquery json .. sort data array custom list .. how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want sort values ​​by array Another

for example

```
var objName = [{id:1, name:"one"},{id:2, name:"two"}, {id:3, name:"three"}];
var sortById = [1,3,2];
```

I want this output in that order

```
1 one
3 three
2 two
```

Comment: Can we see your unsuccessful attempts?

Answer (score 2):

Stuff `objName` elements into a hash (i.e. object) indexed by `id`, then `map` the `sortById` array onto the hash values.

Exact code left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The ideal answer for the given question in my humble opinion. I wish I could +1 once again

Comment: @Nick Manning: you're confusing the teaching process with crowd funding.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted=new Array()
for(var id_index=0;id_index<sortById.length;id_index++)
{
    for(var obj_index=0;obj_index<objName.length;obj_index++){
        if (objName[obj_index].id===sortById[id_index]) sorted.push(objName[obj_index])
    }
}
//now sorted is the new sorted array. if you want to overwrite the original object:
objName=sorted;
```

Comment: Won't work, he wants to sort by id. Who says the ids are in the correct order in the first array?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the length of both arrays are the same you can first create a hash:

```
var objName = [{id:1, name:"one"},{id:2, name:"two"}, {id:3, name:"three"}];
var myHash = {};
for(var i = 0; i<objName.length;i++){
    myHash[objName[i].id] = objName[i];
}
```

Once you have this hash, you can loop over your keys array and get the values out:

```
var sortById = [1,3,2];
var sortedArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i<sortById.length;i++){
    sortedArray.push(myHash[sortById[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something clear and readable (subjective, probably not for everyone):

```
var result = [];
sortById.forEach(function(id) {
    result = result.concat(objName.filter(function(i) {
        return i.id == id;
    }));
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RLH6F/

Implemented just for fun.

Warning: `O(n^2)`

PS: I agree it would be better just give the recipe without the code, but as soon as there are already community members provided the copy-paste solutionы I decided to provide at least a nice looking one.